# Creating X childs using fork() in a process tree when SIGINT is recieved in C

Tags: c, process, tree, fork

I have been struggling with this for a while and I gave up so I'm asking for help.

I need to write a program that waits permanently for SIGINT (Ctrl + C) and when recieved, the last generation process(es) create X childs. You'd say it is a "Xary" tree (correct me if I'm wrong somehow).

So:

When recieved once SIGINT:

```
$ pstree -p 6227
example(6227) example(6229)
              example(6230)
```

When recieved twice:

```
$ pstree -p 6227
             example(6229) example(6235)
                           example(6236)
tarea2(6227)
             example(6230) example(6234)
                           example(6237)
```

And so on...

So far I'm able to catch the SIGINT, but after many failed attempts, I've got nothing on how to create the tree.

So, this is my code:
(Please ignore the unused includes)

```
#include <stdio.h> /* libreria estandar */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define X 2

void reproducir(int signum)
{
 if (signum == SIGINT)
        switch(signum)
    {
        case SIGINT:
            /*SOMETHING I'VE BEEN TRYING TO FIGURE OUT*/
    }
        }
int main(void)
{
                printf("PID: %d\n", getpid()); 

    while (1)
    { 
        if (signal(SIGINT, reproducir) == SIG_ERR) 
        {
            perror("error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } 
}
```

Many thanks in advance, I'm sorry for any gramatic mistakes, native spanish speaker here.

Comment: You might like to also show us **how you used `fork()`** and tell us which problems you faced.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
int reproducir(void)
{
if (spawn == 0){
for (i=0;i < X;i++)
        {
                    spawn = fork();
                    if(spawn == 0) {
                      break;
                    }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```